# Error al ejecutar JSTL en IntelliJ

Tags: jsp, tomcat, maven, intellij-idea, jstl

Tengo un problema, y es que cuando intento usar la libreria de jstl, me sale el siguiente problema, Estoy usando Intellij IDE:

[image: Resultado al ejecutar el servidor Apache tomcat]

**las dependencias de mi archivo pom.xml están así:**

[image: Archivo pom.xml, dependencias]

**index.jsp**

[image: Dependencias del archivo pom.xml]

```
Estructura del código en jsp, como pueden ver, tan solo uso la libreria jstl
```

Tengo entendido que el error es de dependencias, he probado varias soluciones y ninguna me funciona. ¿Qué es lo que me falta hacer?

EDIT:
Estructura del proyecto: no tengo nada más que un archivo jsp

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

Estoy usando Tomcat 9.0.38
El error que me sale en el TomcatLog:

> 27-Oct-2020 08:49:52.005 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Prueba_war] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: intenté recuperar tus imágenes, pero parece que la de tu pom no se subió, por favor intenta agregarla

Comment: Buenas tardes Gustavo, viendo tu código y comparándolo con versiones de mis proyectos en Spring, el taglib lo tengo pegado al <%@, no sé si eso será suficiente para que te saque el error, pero pruébalo y me dices.

De paso, ¿podrías subir el controlador principal?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido! Por favor, procura compartir tu código y las trazas de error como texto. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @SergioGarridoDomínguez gracias por tu respuesta, no me ha funcionado. No estoy utilizando ningún controlador, Solo había creado un proyecto java web y añadí un archivo jsp.

Comment: Qué versión de Tomcat estás usando? Y lo otro, por favor revisa los logs de tomcat (/logs/catalina.out por ejemplo) y trae la traza completa del error (edita tu pregunta con la info que encuentres).

Comment: @Alfabravo Estoy utilizando tomcat 9.0.38.  El error: 27-Oct-2020 08:49:52.005 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Prueba_war] threw exception [The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Cuando te hagamos sugerencias, por favor procura revisarlas y seguirlas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que la dependencia está mal indicada, por lo que JSTL no se carga en el classpath. La forma correcta de incluir JSTL es (mira el groupId):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Buenas, lo cambié tal cual lo escribiste, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Revisa que en las dependencias del proyecto se haya actualizado y cargado la librería

Comment: ya lo hice, pero me sigue saliendo error